# Possible update in bokeh is causing a strange generator bug

Tags: python, bokeh

I had the following code snippet working:

```
import numpy as np
import bokeh.plotting as bp
from bokeh.models import HoverTool 
bp.output_file('test.html')

fig = bp.figure(tools="reset,hover")
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)
s1 = fig.scatter(x=x,y=y1,color='#0000ff',size=10,legend='sine')
s1.select(dict(type=HoverTool)).tooltips = {"x":"$x", "y":"$y"}
s2 = fig.scatter(x=x,y=y2,color='#ff0000',size=10,legend='cosine')
fig.select(dict(type=HoverTool)).tooltips = {"x":"$x", "y":"$y"}
bp.show()
```

no the liine s1.select ... returns a generator and gives me the following bug:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'tooltips'
```

A server update took place for the process that is running this code. It is possible that bokeh may have been updated. Whats my fastest workaround this ?? or is there a bug I am missing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some time ago the glyph methods were changed to return the glyph renderer, instead of the plot. This makes configuring the visual properties of the glyph renderer much easier. Returning the plot was redundant, since a user typically already has a reference to the plot. But you want to search the plot for a hover tool, not the glyph renderer, so you need to do:

```
fig.select(HoverTool).tooltips = {"x":"$x", "y":"$y"}
```

Note that using a dictionary means there is no guarantee about the order of the tooltips. If you care about the order, you should use a list of tuples:

```
fig.select(HoverTool).tooltips = [("x", "$x"), ("y", "$y")]
```

Then the tooltip rows will show up in the same order as given, top to bottom.

Comment: hmmm this wont work though? since I have different scatter plots on the same fig see ?

Comment: putting `"hover"` in the `tools` argument only creates *one* hover tool. If you want multiple, differently configured hover tools, you will have to be a bit more explicit. See, e.g. https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/models/sprint.py#L102 for an example of adding a hover tool "by  hand" and configuring it with a specific renderer